# Gnuplot - Multiplot autoscale displays x-axis and y-axis units twice on each other

Tags: gnuplot

In Gnuplot I want to display 2 plots on the same graph with the help of multiplot. The display works fine, but the scaling redisplays and the same units are put on each other, because i use autoscale.

My question is, how do i display the scaling only once?

Here is my code:

```
set border 1023-128
set autoscale

set multiplot 
plot strDsDir.strInputFile using 1:($6/1000000) skip 1 w filledcurves x lc rgb "#00aa22"
replot strDsDir.strInputFile using 1:($7/1000000) skip 1 w filledcurves x lc rgb "#80e45f"
unset multiplot
```

I tried unsetting autoscale, between the "plot" and "replot", but then I lose autoscaling, and graphs slip.

I also tried unsetting xtics and ytics, but then i lose the `set border 1023-128` above.

Here is the picture, where my units lapse on eachother : 
[image]

And here is the picture, where units dont lapse on each other, but my "set border option" disappears : 
[image]

The dataset what im trying to display doesnt matter. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of multiplot usually is to plot several plots beside each other. If you want to plot several curves in a single plot, use a single plot command like `plot x, x**2`:

```
plot strDsDir.strInputFile using 1:($6/1e6) skip 1 w filledcurves x lc rgb "#00aa22", \
    "" using 1:($7/1e6) skip 1 w filledcurves x lc rgb "#80e45f"
```